# How to reproduce that array efficiently in python/numpy?

Tags: random, scipy, numpy-ndarray, random-seed

I have the following array that I want to reproduce using sp.random.seed(10):

[[ 0.          0.09174312  0.18348624  0.27522936  0.36697248  0.4587156
   0.55045872  0.64220183  0.73394495  0.82568807  0.91743119  1.00917431
   1.10091743  1.19266055  1.28440367  1.37614679  1.46788991  1.55963303
   1.65137615  1.74311927  1.83486239  1.9266055   2.01834862  2.11009174
   2.20183486  2.29357798  2.3853211   2.47706422  2.56880734  2.66055046
   2.75229358  2.8440367   2.93577982  3.02752294  3.11926606  3.21100917
   3.30275229  3.39449541  3.48623853  3.57798165  3.66972477  3.76146789
   3.85321101  3.94495413  4.03669725  4.12844037  4.22018349  4.31192661
   4.40366972  4.49541284  4.58715596  4.67889908  4.7706422   4.86238532
   4.95412844  5.04587156  5.13761468  5.2293578   5.32110092  5.41284404
   5.50458716  5.59633028  5.68807339  5.77981651  5.87155963  5.96330275
   6.05504587  6.14678899  6.23853211  6.33027523  6.42201835  6.51376147
   6.60550459  6.69724771  6.78899083  6.88073394  6.97247706  7.06422018
   7.1559633   7.24770642  7.33944954  7.43119266  7.52293578  7.6146789
   7.70642202  7.79816514  7.88990826  7.98165138  8.0733945   8.16513761
   8.25688073  8.34862385  8.44036697  8.53211009  8.62385321  8.71559633
   8.80733945  8.89908257  8.99082569  9.08256881  9.17431193  9.26605505
   9.35779817  9.44954128  9.5412844   9.63302752  9.72477064  9.81651376
   9.90825688 10.        ]]

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is just the result of a linear spacing between two endpoints. The code below reproduces it.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.linspace(0, 10, 110))
```